# Using json to add values to a class and create a listview in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I know I am missing something very fundamental here but I am attempting to use some json to create a list of cards in flutter. i am very new to coding and am not understanding the creation of a class constructor and the application of the json to it. i can receive the response and by printing to the console i can see that i can parse the json but having it appear as text on the cards is where i am having issues. Any help is appreciated in applying the json to the class and I plan to use a listview to populate the card details.

This is the code for the api call and the widget build:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './views.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:convert';

class BodyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ViewObject> fetcheddata = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    testapi();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: fetcheddata.length,
      itemBuilder: cardBuilder,
    );
  }

  Widget cardBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: Text(thisobject.brandname), etc etc
    );
  }

  void testapi() async {
    http
        .get('urlgoeshere')
        .then((http.Response response) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> viewslistdata = json.decode(response.body);
      viewslistdata.forEach((String view, dynamic viewdata) {
        ViewObject thisobject = ViewObject(
            brandName: viewdata['brandname'],
            appName: viewdata['appname'],
            views: viewdata['Views']);
        fetcheddata.add(thisobject);

      });
    });
  }
}
```

and this is the class constructor

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ViewObject {
  final String appName;
  final String brandName;
  final int views;

  ViewObject(
      {@required this.appName , @required this.brandName, @required this.views});    
  }
```

As you can tell I am new to coding and especially dart/flutter so apologies for the bad code. I have searched for an answer but not found anything to help fully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `StatelessWidget` into a `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` on `fetcheddata.add(thisobject)`

```
setState((){
fetcheddata.add(thisobject);
})
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work, I'm now trying to use a future builder using: https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

Comment: I noticed you are calling you `async` function in build method while you need to call it from initState, future builder is good alternative too

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use a futurebuilder and am having some success with a single Map but am unsure how to convert it to use the list of Maps to return as many cards as are in the list. Link to my new question is:  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121211/convert-single-api-reponse-to-a-list-of-maps-to-convert-to-cards-in-flutter)