# Convert Single API reponse to a list of Maps to convert to cards in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, future

I have used the flutter cookbook to create a Future in order to convert a single Map into a card. However I want to do this with a list of Maps. I know I need to create a list and then use the futurebuilder to return a list view, but I am unsure how to add to the apitest() method to add each Map to a list to then convert. Any help is much appreciated.

This is main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './viewviews.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'API TEST',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: CardPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my class to construct the object:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Post {
  final String appName;
  final String brandName;
  final int views;

  Post(
      {@required this.appName, @required this.brandName, @required this.views});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return (Post(
        views: json['Views'],
        brandName: json['brandname'],
        appName: json['appname']));
  }
}
```

and finally the code I am using to make the api call and use the futurebuilder:

```
import 'dart:async';

//final List<Post> cardslist = [];

class CardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('API TEST')),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: cardbuilder,
          itemCount: 1,
        ));
  }
}

Future<Post> testapi() async {
  final apiresponse =
      await http.get('https://myriadapp-55adf.firebaseio.com/Views.json');
  print(apiresponse.body);
  return Post.fromJson(json.decode(apiresponse.body));
}

Widget cardbuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
          future: testapi(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.appName);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.hasError.toString());
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }));
}
```

I have commented out the code to create the list but I know I will need this, I just need to decode the json to add a list of Maps to it and then use Futurebuilder to return the listview. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json doesn't actually return a json array, it actually returns a map with arbitrary key names like `View1`, so we'll iterate that map. You need to hoist your `FutureBuilder` up to the point where you can deal with the whole json at once, so at the page level. So `CardPage` becomes

```
class CardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('API TEST')),
      body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;
            final List<Container> cards = data.keys
                .map((String s) => makeCard(Post.fromJson(data[s])))
                .toList();
            return ListView(
              children: cards,
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.hasError.toString());
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Container makeCard(Post post) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Text(post.appName),
    );
  }

  Future<Map> fetchData() async {
    final apiresponse =
        await http.get('https://myriadapp-55adf.firebaseio.com/Views.json');
    print(apiresponse.body);
    return json.decode(apiresponse.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much Richard. Just one final query, as the future builder returns just a listview, is it more performant to retrun a listview.builder or does the futurebuilder cover the performance aspect? Thanks again.

Comment: That really depends on how big your list is. Since your API response contains the whole list, it's simplest to make the whole `ListView` using its 'normal' constructor. If performance suffers with a large list, you could just build a list of `Post`s instead of `Container`s and return a `ListView.builder` which would build each `Container` on demand. You would know the size of the `Post` list, which could be needed for the `.builder` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, making these changes and a few others including initialising the cars list outside of the main functions worked a treat and I am now using a `listview.builder` to generate a performant list. Thanks again.